# Defeated elite four, but somehow missed Blue’s mega stones. Can they still be gotten?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

My son has defeated the elite four, but for some reason doesn’t have Blue’s mega stones. Can he still get them?

According to https://www.serebii.net/letsgopikachueevee/gyms.shtml, one should receive Blue's mega stones before entering the 8th gym. However, we cannot find the stones anywhere in his inventory. He also doesn't recall receiving them before entering the 8th, but it's been quite a while since he first entered it.

We've tried revisiting the 7th and 8th gyms, as well as professor Oak's lab, but no luck. Blue is not there. The only place we can now find Blue is as the boss at the Viridian City gym, where we can battle him, but he doesn't give us the mega stones.

Also, what could he possible have done that would result in not getting Blue’s mega stones? Can you refuse them when they are offered to you? Could he have sold them? If he did sell them, would it be possIble to buy them back from the shop to which he sold them?

Could he have left or stored them somewhere else in the game? Is that even possible?

If he did still have them, where in his inventory would they be?

Comment: Have you visited Professor Oak? If I recall correctly, Blue will be in  Pallet town after defeating the 8th gym leader

Comment: Serebii states that you get them from Blue after trying to enter Viridian City Gym

Comment: @Wondercricket Yes, I updated my answer.

Comment: @pinckerman My son already beat all the gyms quite a while ago. Like I said, he beat the elite four. Yet, he does not have Blue mega stones anywhere in his inventory. When we now visit the Viridian City Gym, Blue is not there. I updated my answer with more info.

Comment: They could have been sold, then. The point is if he remembers to have received them.

Comment: @pinckerman Can mega stones even be sold? I can check later today, but I don't remember that being an option

Comment: @Wondercricket And now I'm curious. I've never tried, but... why not? They have a sell price (0, btw) and are not stored in key items section.

Comment: If he sold them, would it be possible to buy them back from the store he sold them to?

Comment: What is the key items section? If he still had them, where in his inventory would they appear?

Comment: So, I decided to have a look myself in his inventory and I found them!  See my answer, below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- All mega stones can be found in your **battle pocket** (not your power-up pocket).
- Mega stones do **not** have the words “mega stone” in their name or description. Instead, the stones you get from Blue are called:

  - Key stone (not an actual mega stone, but needed to activate mega stones)
  - **Venusaurite**
  - **Charizardite X**
  - **Charizardite Y**
  - **Blastoisinite**
- The encounter with Blue in which you get the stones [is mostly just lots of text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OS_9X9k_tyY) and you don’t actually get to *see* the mega stones during the encounter. This is likely the reason why your kid doesn’t remember it happened.